# Return a default value in Kotlin for a nullable value that has function chains

Tags: kotlin

Given this code

```
myValue.number?.setScale(2).toString() ?: ""
```

I want it to return `""` if number is `null`. But it just returns `null`. What concept did I not grasp here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is `toString` for nullable types that returns `"null"` if reference (or expression) is null, so in your case, `?: ""` expression is unreachable. Add another null-safe call operator

```
myValue.number?.setScale(2)?.toString() ?: ""
```

You can replace `?: ""` with `.orEmpty()`

```
myValue.number?.setScale(2)?.toString().orEmpty()
```